# IID implies Ergodicity

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The environment space is given by $\Omega:=P^{\mathbb{Z}^{d}}$, where P contains the 2d-vectors serving as admissible transition probabilities. 
An Element $\omega \in \Omega$ is defined as $\omega:=(\omega(x))_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}$, and $\omega(x)=\{\omega(x,e):|e|=1, e\in \mathbb{Z}^d\}$.
We endow $\Omega$ with the product-topology and let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,B(\Omega))$.
**First Question**
If one assume, that the coordinate maps on the product space are iid under $\mathbb{P}$ then that means, that the $\omega(x)$ are iid under law $\mathbb{P}$?
For the second question: We define now translation mapping $t_{y}:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ defined als $(t_{y}\omega)(x,e):=\omega(x+y,e)$.
Then the author says, that under the iid-assumption one gets, that $(\Omega,B(\Omega),(t_{x})_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^d},\mathbb{P})$ is ergodic. **Second Question:** How to prove this? I know, that i need to show, that $t_{x}$ is measure preserving, and i have to show, that $I:=\{A \in B(\Omega): t_{x}^{-1}A=A\}$ is $\mathbb{P}$-trivial for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Ok i will try it. Please have a look on my notation to expose maybe wrong beliefs/ideas on the model. Under the first assumption one can write $\mathbb{P}=\mu^{\times \mathbb{Z}^{d}}$ with $\mu$ a measure on P. Then $\mu^{\times \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(t_{x'}^{-1}(\omega))=\mu^{\times \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(\omega(x-x')_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^{d}})=\mu^{\times \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(\omega(x)_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^{d}})$. This shows, that $\mathbb{P}(t_{x'}^{-1}(\omega))=\mathbb{P}(\omega)$. Im stuck on an arbitary set $A \in B(\Omega)$ for the complete proof and measure invariance. I have no idea to show ergodicity.